# Per-job environments in Jenkins with virtualenv

Tags: bash, python, jenkins, virtualenv

I'm trying to use `virtualenv` to programmatically manage Python environments for each job on a Jenkins server, implemented via a [Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/06/27/speaker-blog-SAS-jenkins-world/) extension to activate environments on a per job basis.  E.g.:

`/vars/activateEnvironment.groovy`:

```
def call(String env = "/usr/local/etc/environments/jenkins-$JOB_NAME") {

    sh """
    mkdir ${env}
    virtualenv ${env}
    source ${env}/bin/activate
    """
}
```

Pipeline script, in which the `virtualenv-scripts` repository contains the above file:

```
@Library('virtualenv-scripts') _

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                activateEnvironment()
                sh 'which pip'
                sh 'echo \$PATH'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this pipeline script, I get the following output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[example-pipeline] Running shell script
+ echo /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
[Pipeline] sh
[example-pipeline] Running shell script
+ which pip
/bin/pip
```

I've tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122986/how-can-i-default-to-a-login-shell-for-jenkins-shell-execution) to make Jenkins use a login shell, but that still reloads the environment with every `sh` call.

I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343948/how-can-i-start-a-bash-login-shell-in-jenkins-pipeline-formerly-known-as-workfl) which would require pasting extra text every time a `sh` step is used in a Pipeline -- not ideal.

Is there a good way to have environment persist between `sh` commands?  Alternately, is there a better way to achieve per-job environments with `virtualenv`?  Thanks for all help/suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue.  After talking with some veteran Jenkins admins, this is the solution I arrived at:

```
def runCommandInMyEnvironment(cmd) {
  sh "setup_environment_command; source ./some/file; ${cmd}"
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("My Stage") {
      steps {
        runCommandInMyEnvironment('first_command')
        runCommandInMyEnvironment('second_command')
        // and so on
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not pretty and it can muddy up the console output quite a bit, but it's also the most reliable way to do this.

Another approach would be to parse the output of some command and chop it up into a bunch of environment variables and then pass those to a `withEnv` block, but this can be a very tricky and unreliable approach.

In any case, as you alluded to, Jenkins doesn't support persisting environments without `withEnv`, so ultimately there's no real good or clean way to do it.

There may be a better way to use virtualenvs with Jenkins, but I've never written a Jenkins job that runs tasks in a virtualenv, so I can't say.  There is [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pyenv+Pipeline+Plugin), but [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102124/1824868) suggests that the approach I gave in this answer is the preferred method for working with virtualenvs in Jenkins.

Comment: This seems to work relatively well with `virtualenv`.  If setting up the environment were a heavier-weight task, I wouldn't want to call it a bunch of times, but in my case it is not.  Thanks, @jayhendren

Comment: Great and simple solution! 